# Javascript equivalent to Ruby Time.parse

Tags: javascript, ruby

I allow users to enter datetime in whatever format they like as long as Ruby's Time.parse method can handle it. Now I need to compare these datetimes in javascript. Is there anything equivalent to Ruby's Time.parse method for javascript?

I need something that can parse for instance "October 13 2012 at 8:15am". I tried datejs but it couldn't handle the "at" word. I would really prefer something that only requires a single function call.

Comment: No such thing exists natively in JS. You may have to create a work-around for Date.js.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will find a JS library that accepts input identical to Ruby's `Time.parse`.

Comment: Figured as much but it is nice to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript language is picky (and implementations vary) regarding what date format it accepts, so there's no hope without using a library.

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is easily your best bet; however, as you point out, there are sure to be formats that make perfect sense to users but that the library couldn't anticipate.

To workaround, I suggest that you wrap the Date.js parser in a custom scrubbing function that you must maintain:

```javascript
// using Date.js
function parseDate(str) {
  var wordsToRemove = ['on', 'at'] // ...
    , regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + wordsToRemove.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
  return Date.parse(str.replace(regex, ''));
}
```

Comment: This could work. I would feel better using a whitelist rather than a blacklist though.

Comment: I'd have to look into all the english words used in most date formats but something like is not in ['am', 'pm', 'utc' ...]

Answer (score 0):

[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) has a really impressive stuff to work with dates in javascript

Comment: It fails for parsing "October 13 2012 at 8:15am" like I said.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://momentjs.com/, best time library ever!

Comment: Unfortunately, like datejs it fails for parsing "October 13 2012 at 8:15am"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but hopefully it will still help:

If you're only parsing US locale date strings, check out [Sherlock.js](https://github.com/Tabule/Sherlock).

The only limitation is that it doesn't support specifying years or past dates. It can parse 'October 13 2012 at 8:15am' but it will return a Date object for October 13, 2013 at 8:15am, since it always looks forward. You could write some RegEx, like `/\b20\d\d\b/` to parse out the year from the string yourself though if needed.

*Disclosure:* I am the creator of Sherlock.js

Comment: Impressive. Thanks Neil. I'll give it a try.